# Cannot use color transparency in drawRect

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

I'm having trouble with transparency in drawRect. I have a custom UIView. If I draw a rect bezier path and fill it with gray the color will be solid without any transparency even though I have the alpha set to 0.6. :

import UIKit

```
class MyView: UIView {


    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {


        let grayOverlay = UIBezierPath(rect: rect)
        UIColor(red: 34, green: 211, blue: 121, alpha: 0.6).set()
        grayOverlay.fill()

    }

}
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: is your view opaque? check the opaque property of it

Comment: @Andrea just set it to opaque and no change

Comment: By logic, if you want it transparent, it should NOT be opaque

Comment: @Andrea. Ah! my bad. Sorry. It's working now. If you do the answer I'll accept otherwise I'll just delete this question. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Views have and `-opaque` property. 
By default is set to `true` due to performance reasons. If the view is not opaque it will require transparent blending, that is more intensive.

By setting to `false` you agree to have transparency between your view and what it is displayed under.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.